# I can not reach the array' s previous iteration values in OPL Script

Tags: arrays, optimization, cplex, opl

I have a MIP model in CPlex.

- In each iteration I use different .dat files and solve the problem.
- I hold the decision variable solution values in a multi dimensional array like "Array[iteration][i]", "i" is the decision variable's index and iteration represent the different instances(different .dat files).
- I want to reach "Array[1][i]" when "iteration = 2", it says "Array[1][i]= [a IloNumVar]".

  ```
       main{
           for(var datFile in thisOplModel.datFiles) {
           iteration+=1;
           var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);       
           var data= new IloOplDataSource(datFile);
           opl.addDataSource(data);
           opl.generate(); 
           tempX[iteration]= new Array();
           tempY[iteration]= new Array();

           for(var i =1; i_node<=node; i ++){

               tempX[iteration][i]= new Array();
               tempY[iteration][i]= new Array();

               if (iteration==1){      
                   cplex.solve()
                   tempX[iteration][i]= opl.X[i];  
                   //When I want to print temp[1][i] values at iteration is equal to 1, it print the values.
                   writeln("tempX: ", tempX[1][i]); 

              }
           }       

           if (iteration==2){
               for(var i_node=1; i_node<=node; i_node++){  
               //When I am at iteration 2, i want to reach previous iteration values but it brings "[a IloNumVar]"  
                   writeln("tempX: ", tempX[1][i]);
               }
           }   

      opl.end();

   }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
tempX[iteration][i]= opl.X[i];
```

I would try

```
tempX[iteration][i]= opl.X[i].solutionValue;
```